# Object variable declaration with const

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, destructuring

Need to declare a constant in a object with `errors` being a `const` type and
`aeroPlaneList`, and `airBusDealers` being `let` type

I've tried to declare inside the object `{const errors, ..., ...}` but would cause an error. I've also attempted to declare the constant outside with `const errors;` but that would lead to it having no value(consts can't change).

```
  validateBoeing = event => {
    let { errors, aeroPlaneList, airBusDealers } = Object.assign(
      {},
      this.state
    );
  };
```

Expected result would be that `errors` is a const type that get's it's value from Object.assign(). `aeroPlaneList` and `airBusDealers` remain dynamic variables `let`.

Comment: You'll have to assign them separately.

Comment: What's wrong with separate destructures anyway? Readability > Brevity almost always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll have to declare them in separate statements in order to do so:

```
validateBoeing = event => {
  const state = Object.assign(
    {},
    this.state
  );
  const { errors } = state;
  let { aeroPlaneList, airBusDealers } = state;
}
```